# JS callback for grid action

Tags: magento2, javascript, adminhtml, grid, knockoutjs

I see I can use custom action handlers for adminhtml grid actions. This is DOM node for action link (HTML):

```
<a class="action-menu-item"
        data-bind="attr: {href: $action().href}, 
                   text: $action().label, 
                   click: $col.getActionHandler($action())"
        data-repeat-index="0"
        href="http://.../index.php/admin/customer/index/edit/id/1/">Edit</a>
```

I have created additional action in adminhtml grid with callback data (PHP code):

```
$actions['alert'] = [
    'label' => __('Alert'),
    'callback' => 'function() {alert("Action!")}'
];
```

This action is converted into JSON and is loaded to the grid in this format, where "callback" property is a string (JSON):

```
"alert": {
  "label": "Alert",
  "callback": "function() {alert(\"Action!\")}"
}
```

This is Magento parser for action's props (`module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/actions.js`). This parser process JSON data and should call action's callback in case of callback is object/array/function (see `_getCallback`):

```
getActionHandler: function (action) {
    var index = action.index,
        rowIndex = action.rowIndex;

    if (this.isHandlerRequired(index, rowIndex)) {
        return this.applyAction.bind(this, index, rowIndex);
    }
},

applyAction: function (actionIndex, rowIndex) {
    debugger
    var action = this.getAction(rowIndex, actionIndex),
        callback = this._getCallback(action);

    action.confirm ?
        this._confirm(action, callback) :
        callback();

    return this;
},

_getCallback: function (action) {
    var args = [action.index, action.recordId, action],
        callback = action.callback;

    if (utils.isObject(callback)) {
        args.unshift(callback.target);

        callback = registry.async(callback.provider);
    } else if (_.isArray(callback)) {
        return this._getCallbacks(action);
    } else if (!_.isFunction(callback)) {
        callback = this.defaultCallback.bind(this);
    }

    return function () {
        callback.apply(callback, args);
    };
},
```

But `callback` property is a string, so `defaultCallback` is used.

How can I use my own action handler in adminhtml grid actions?

Comment: did you got fix for you own issue ?

Comment: as I recall, I created own action handler: https://github.com/praxigento/mobi_mod_mage2_accounting/blob/master/src/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/actions.js

Answer (score 4):

Update mass-action action in the grid component xml as below:

```
        <action name="add">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Data</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Data ?</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Data</item>
                    <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">my_form.my_form.field_data</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">addData</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
```

Here, **my_form.my_form.field_data** is my form namespace and file name.

**field_data** is my text field.

Below is my field with custom js component:

```
<field name="field_data">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">My_Module/js/data</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">my_form_form_data_source</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Mass Action Data</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

**data.js** component file:

```js
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract'
    ], function (_, uiRegistry, Abstract) {
    'use strict';
```

`return Abstract.extend({
    addData: function (action, data) {
        var itemsType = data.excludeMode ? 'excluded' : 'selected',
            selections = {};

        selections[itemsType] = data[itemsType];

        if (!selections[itemsType].length) {
            selections[itemsType] = false;
        }

        _.extend(selections, data.params || {});

        console.log(selections); // you mass action value.

    }
});
});`

You can use any component js to handle the callback. I used my field component js and saved the data in the form field.